# Confusion with units of angular velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, units, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I know that the SI unit of angular velocity is $s^{-1}$ (because radians or angle measure is dimensionless). I encountered a question that said:

> Given angular velocity = $12 \, s^{-1}$ and angular acceleration = $6\,s^{-2}$.

I have never had a question with this kind of unit. Usually units such as rad/s, deg/s, rpm, revolutions/s (angular velocity) are encountered but this question does not have a measure of angle attached.

I think it can be interpreted as any of this rad/s, deg/s or etc. One of colleague said:

> If it's $s^{-1}$ it means it is $1\,\text{rad}\cdot s^{-1}$.

**Is my colleague right? Is the question incomplete or I am missing something here?**

Comment: I think the question is ambiguous, but your colleague may be right. ;) What's the context of the question? Is it in a textbook? If so, does the textbook assume the students know calculus, and are familar with radian measure?

Comment: @PM2Ring It's not in a textbook because generally in textbooks it is clearly mentioned. can you tell why my colleague can be correct? thanks for the help

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.